# Customizing hv.Arrow Holoviews annotation

Tags: python, bokeh, holoviews

Here is a simple plot with an arrow annotation. Is it possible to change the length, start/stop coordinates and other parameters with this arrow and the text similar to to documentation in [bokeh](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/annotations.html#arrows)? All I could find is this [documentation](http://holoviews.org/reference/elements/bokeh/Arrow.html) that only shows some simple ways to change the direction and type of arrow.

```
import numpy as np
import holoviews as hv
hv.extension('bokeh')

points = [(1*i, np.sin(.1*i)*10) for i in range(100)]
curve = hv.Curve(points)


curve * hv.Arrow(45,-5, 'Inflection', 'v')
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can.

[here](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/annotations.html#arrows) you can see a little example. and if you want to look at what do you want to change, look [here](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/reference/models/annotations.html#bokeh.models.annotations.Arrow)